# jQuery.ajax() submit form directly to browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm returning a `JsonResult` from an ASP.NET MVC Action. The json object returned contains two properties:

- `_Success`: Can be true or false
- `_Response`: Containing response message (could be the same form loaded with modal validation)

What happens is that, inside the `Success` function of `$.ajax()`, I am checking on the `result._Success`, etc ...

What actually happens, is that the URL is browsed to instead of sending an ajax request.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the submit event returns false.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $.ajax(..);

  return false;
});
```

The return false will cancel the main submit event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you post some code, your problem cannot be commented upon. However for **ajaxifying** forms there is this [wonderful jQuery plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) which lets you submit your form with Ajax with minimal code. Essesntially you will only have to put `$('#myFormId').ajaxForm();` if you have your validations inside `pattern` attribute of your input fields.

Comment: The validation scripts were missing hence, JS was crashing when it hits the call for $.valdiator.unobtrusive.parse(), hence, binding the submit event of the form was not happening, that's why the form was posting directly to browser.